# Correct DateTime format for DataContractJsonSerializerSettings

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-4.5, datacontractjsonserializer

- Using 4.5
- According to a requirements of a project already build, using Newtonsoft.Json in one side and DataContractJsonSerializer in other side of the server.

I tried already two different configurations found here in order to parse DataTime `2017-10-17T17:22:50.658+02:00`. The other solutions are related to not using the `DataContractJsonSerializer`but it's not my solution.

Configurations that I already tried:

```
DateTime example = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "2017-10-17T17:22:50.658+02:00",
    "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

- Without specify any date time format in settings

  ```
  private static DataContractJsonSerializerSettings GetSerializerSettings()
  {
      var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();

      settings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true;
      settings.EmitTypeInformation = System.Runtime.Serialization.EmitTypeInformation.Never;

      return settings;
  }
  ```

I got `DateTime '2017-10-18T13:32:42.753+02:00' are not startingwith '\/Date(' and ending with ')\/' as JSON requires` as error message.

- Specifying a date time format in settings

  ```
  private static DataContractJsonSerializerSettings GetSerializerSettings()
  {
      var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();
      settings.DateTimeFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.DateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz");

      settings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true;
      settings.EmitTypeInformation = System.Runtime.Serialization.EmitTypeInformation.Never;
      return settings;
  }
  ```

I got `Can't recognize as valid DateTime` as error message.

Any tip?

Comment: By the way, you should use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` for serialization.

Comment: I changed it, but still having same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffK")
};
```